# Publicize.exe exits with error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name : interfaceType

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, private-methods

I'm trying to make private accessor class using Visual Studio 2010.

Here is the return of Publicize.exe:

```
Error occurred during processing of assembly xxx Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: interfaceType
```

I use internals and InternalVisibleTo in my project. Perhaps that is the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have an event in an internal interface within your module?

There's a bug about it:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/481332/creating-a-private-accessor-when-you-have-a-top-level-friend-interface-exposing-an-event-fails-in-publicize